# Use jQuery to Sort DIV based on Grandchild DIVS

Tags: jquery, sorting, html

I have spent the last day scouring Stack and have not found the answer to this problem, even though there are very similar solutions.  This is the code the HTML that I am working with:

```
<div class="titles">
    <div class="filename" id="sfilename"><strong>Name</strong></div>
    <div class="filesize" id="sfilesize"><strong>Size</strong></div>
    <div class="filetype" id="sfiletype"><strong>Type</strong></div>
    <div class="filedate" id="sfiledate"><strong>Last Modified</strong></div>
</div>

<div id="sort">
    <div class="folder">
        <div class="filename">Folder 1</div>
    <div class="filesize">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="filetype">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="filedate">May 12 2012 11:24:44 AM</div>
    </div>
    <div class="folder">
        <div class="filename">Folder 2</div>
    <div class="filesize">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="filetype">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="filedate">May 15 2012 09:24:44 AM</div>
    </div>
    <div class="folder">
        <div class="filename">Folder 3</div>
    <div class="filesize">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="filetype">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="filedate">May 18 2012 12:24:44 AM</div>
    </div>

    <div class="file">
        <div class="filename">File 1</div>
    <div class="filesize">7.38 Kb</div>
        <div class="filetype">png</div>
        <div class="filedate">May 18 2012 08:24:44 AM</div>
    </div>
    <div class="file">
        <div class="filename">File 2</div>
    <div class="filesize">58.2 Kb</div>
        <div class="filetype">jpg</div>
        <div class="filedate">May 16 2012 07:24:44 AM</div>
    </div>
    <div class="file">
        <div class="filename">File 3</div>
    <div class="filesize">135.87 Kb</div>
        <div class="filetype">mov</div>
        <div class="filedate">May 10 2012 05:24:44 AM</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to be able to sort within the #sort div based on the contents of the #filename, #filesize, #filetype or #filedate div's.

I have already tried this with Javascript and it did not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
        var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}

$('#sfilename').data("sortKey", "#filename");
$('#sfilesize').data("sortKey", "#filesize");
$('#sfiletype').data("sortKey", "#filetype");
$('#sfiledate').data("sortKey", "#filedate");

$("#sfilename").click(function() {
   sortUsingNestedText($('#sort'), "div", $("#sfilename").data("sortKey"));
});

$("#sfilesize").click(function() {
   sortUsingNestedText($('#sort'), "div", $("#sfilesize").data("sortKey"));
});

$("#sfiletype").click(function() {
   sortUsingNestedText($('#sort'), "div", $("#sfiletype").data("sortKey"));
});

$("#sfiledate").click(function() {
   sortUsingNestedText($('#sort'), "div", $("#sfiledate").data("sortKey"));
});

</script>
```

Comment: Specify how you want to sort them. By filename, filesize, type or date? Or all of them? Through some kind of `select`? Try to reproduce the environment in a http://fiddle.net please.

Comment: I have created a fiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/K9qNm/4/

Comment: You forgot to quote some selectors: `$(#sfilename)` and the other 3, but that doesn't solve the issue still.

Comment: I guess `.sort()` isn't a jQuery method either, using `.get()` to get the literal DOM elements would be another step forward. You could also use an [already made plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo), but I'll take a look at your function still.

Comment: I think I just figured it out! http://jsfiddle.net/K9qNm/6/ Now I just need to get it to reverse the sort if the button is clicked again.

Comment: Oh nicely done. =] You'll probably have problems sorting some fields alphabetically, say, right now `135.87 Kb` < `58.2 Kb` < `7.38 Kb`, but it looks really good for the amount of code.

Comment: I will be able to get around the sorting problem on the date by having it output as "m-d-Y h:i:s A".  As for the file size... I think I might have to disable that one until I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: You can also create a switch storing the current `order_by` value (`asc`/`desc`) inside the caller element and passing it through a parameter, I'm just not sure what's the best way to implement it inside the `sort` function.

Comment: Here's a (really) ugly workaround, but I guess you can simplify it a bit. =] http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/K9qNm/9/

Comment: Oh, I simplified it a bit, now it should be usable: http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/K9qNm/10/

Comment: That is awesome Fabricio! Thank you! If you want to post your fiddle in the answers section.  I want to be able to give you credit for all of your help!  Last on my list to do now is to make the filename list everything in alphabetical order but always show the folders before the files.  This is the Javascript I was using for that originally:

var statusOrder = ["folder", "file"];
$("#sfilename").click(function(){
    statusOrder.reverse();
    for (var i = 0; i < statusOrder.length; i++) {
        $("#sort ." + statusOrder[i]).appendTo("#sort");
    }
});

Comment: I see. If you could change the letters to after the folder/file, like `Folder A` `Folder B` etc they'd grouped together. I'm not sure how you'd do to make it display the folders always on top, but let me see. :P

Comment: Making a separate sorter for the folders could do it as well.

Comment: I just opened up a few file management programs and all of them sort with ascending - folders on the top and descending - folders on the bottom.  I guess I could enclose the folders like `[A Folder]` ... Nevermind I just tried it and brackets put the folders at the bottom on ascending.

Comment: I had to add a couple workarounds (which you can try to simplify later), take a look if this is close to what you want http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/K9qNm/13/ (you can remove the `.get().reverse()` from folders if you want to display them in normal order when ordering `desc` also)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12221/discussion-between-prince-and-fabricio-matte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store a switch in the callers' `data`, then split your `folder`/`file` jQuery objects to organize it the way you want.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/K9qNm/14/) - I'm using the data property to store `order_by` as the next order it will apply to the sorting when clicked. I simplified the fiddle a little more than in the last comment as well. =]